# How to change window/widget with PyQt5 using .ui files?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

first of all thanks for your time and sorry for the question length, the real question is just the first part.
I can't understand ho to realize a 'page' change, like a web application.
I would like to do that using .ui files, representing widgets or main windows.
Basically, I would like to have two classes, each one mapped with an .ui file implementing a view, and switch between the two views when a button is clicked.

I would like to have is something like that:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        # then load the home page file home.ui

class HomePage:
    def method_0(self):
        # method to load and show the home.ui file, at startup

    def method_1(self):
        # method to load and show the home.ui file, when a button in Second Page is pressed

class SecondPage
    def method_1(self):
        # method to load and show the second.ui file when a button in HomePage is pressed

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

After lots of researches I wrote the code below that almost realize that, I said almost because I must use the same class for all. What I want instead is to have one .py file for each .ui file to keep things separated.

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QStackedWidget

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(800, 620)
        self.central_widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)
        self.home_page()

    def home_page(self):
        widget = uic.loadUi('home.ui')
        self.central_widget.addWidget(widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget)
        widget.change_btn.clicked.connect(self.second_page)

    def second_page(self):
        widget = uic.loadUi('second.ui')
        self.central_widget.addWidget(widget)
        self.central_widget.setCurrentWidget(widget)
        widget.change_btn.clicked.connect(self.home_page)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

And this is the code for both .ui files, just change the filename to `home.ui` and `second.ui`, and change btn text to see the page change. They are simple widgets with one button each

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>620</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Application</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="title" stdset="0">
    <string>GroupBox</string>
   </property>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="change_btn">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>285</x>
      <y>170</y>
      <width>230</width>
      <height>40</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="font">
     <font>
      <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     </font>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>Change page</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>26</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood you completely. You want a *single* main window, and show different "pages" that should load their own .ui files, and have the code that loads those "pages" in separate files?

Comment: Yes, exactly.
It don't have to be a 'single main window', everything is fine if it works, but I don't want that the user sees the window closing  and reopening with the new page (that happened to me when I tried to use two main windows)

Comment: For example a 'Home.py' file with the {HomePage} class that load the 'home.ui file and have methods for the buttons functionalities, most important the method to go to another class that rapresent another .ui code.
The code that I have right now doen't have different classes for different pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is to create separate *widgets* (not windows). While this is already covered in other similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842776/how-to-change-ui-in-same-window-using-pyqt5), I'll answer anyway due to the different files request.

The solution is still the same, using a [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html), that allows you to switch between different widgets that occupy the same part of the window, similarly to what QTabWidget does, but without the tab bar.

First, you need to create a main window in designer, add a QStackedWidget there and ensure that you remove *all* of its pages (right click on the stacked widget, and select "Delete" in the "Page x of x" sub menu).
Then create separate **widgets** (just select "Widget" in the dialog that appears when creating a new form) for each page.

Finally, use `loadUi` on the main window and on each child widget.
I'll recommend you to keep the logic of the page switching in the code of the main window, instead of having it in the different pages, as it's a better and cleaner approach having a "parent" controller when dealing with this situations.

pages.py:

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from first import First
from second import Second

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('pages.ui', self)
        self.first = First()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.first)
        self.first.change_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_second)
        self.second = Second()
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.second)
        self.second.change_btn.clicked.connect(self.go_to_first)

    def go_to_first(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)

    def go_to_second(self):
        self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

first.py

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class First(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi('first.ui', self)
```

second.py

```
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget

class Second(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        uic.loadUi('second.ui', self)
```

There is also the possibility of using [QWizard](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwizard.html), but it's usually suggested for more complex cases than yours.

Comment: Thank you man, it's exactly what I was looking for.
Just another question, to be sure I understood you correctly:
you suggest to code into the main window all the switching widgets logic, and in the single widget classes code the logic of the widget itself, right?
Is this also valid if I'll use 10-12 widgets? And finally, do I have to care about the stacked widget length? Or I can put in it as many widgets I want?
Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @mda yes, exactly: you should always (or, at least, whenever it is possible) keep the logic in the object in which it is executed. All internal objects of the widget that interact between themselves will do so within the class, you should only act on the parent class whenever the interaction is between *other* classes (like in your case, changing pages), otherwise it wouldn't make very much sense to have everything in different classes. If you have similar widgets, you can subclass your own subclasses. There is "theoretically" no limit in the number of widgets except from ram and maybe int.