# PyQt GUI application multiple pages

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

So I am trying to create an application with multiple pages. I would like to have some kind of menu, that the user could use to navigate between different "pages" the application has.

I looked at QStackedWidget, but it seemed like in this case (using uic to load the ui) I would have to write the whole business logic (for all the pages) in a single class, and even if I managed to separate them to some degree, it just seems not that good of a solution. I would also not like to create a new window for every page, would be better to keep them on a single page and just switch on certain events.

I took a look at custom widgets, but I imagine the ideal usecase for those would be for reusability and not for a "page" in an application like this.

What would you recommend?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: My question is, what would be a good solution to implement this kind of functionality, since QStackedWidget and custom widgets just don't seem like a good way to go.

Comment: QStackedWidget can be used to create a user interface similar to the one provided by QTabWidget. It is a convenience layout widget built on top of the QStackedLayout class.  See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A6622587+QStackedWidget

Comment: I got that part, but is it really a good idea to (suppose I have 5 pages) implement all business logic in the class that has the QStackedWidget? Is there a good way to separate the pages somehow in a way that it doesn't become a nightmare?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem with the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904814/how-to-change-window-widget-with-pyqt5-using-ui-files) question. I was confused since the widget I added to the StackedWidget just wouldn't appear.