# Proper way of managing multiple windows in PySide?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I have this app where I have several settings windows that open when buttons from the main window are clicked. The windows are application modal, so only one is open at a time. I have two ideas as to how to manage them, but I'm not sure which one would be the proper way to do it. I don't particularly care how the values are stored, as long as I can pass them to other windows in the app and do stuff with them.

MainWindow class Option 1:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        button = QPushButton('Show window')
        layout.addWidget(button)
        window = OtherWindow()
        button.clicked.connect(window.show)
        # I can pull the settings and pass them on to other windows if needed.
        self.setCentralWidget(central)
```

MainWindow class Option 2:

```
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.other_settings = {}
        button = QPushButton('Show window')
        button.clicked.connect(self.show_other)

    def show_other(self):
        other_window = OtherWindow()
        if other_window.exec():
            self.other_settings.update(other_window.settings)
```

OtherWindow class:

```
class OtherWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.settings = {}
    
        # widgets
        box = QSpinBox(objectName='spinbox')
        box.valueChanged.connect(self.save_settings)
        # and so on ...

    def save_settings(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.settings[sender.objectName()] = sender.value()
```

Comment: If the settings should be shared and consistent during the lifespan of the program, a solution would be to make it an instance attribute of the main window, and pass it as argument whenever you create the dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

If i've understood your question correctly, look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60904814/how-to-change-window-widget-with-pyqt5-using-ui-files) which might be useful.

Small addition from me is, [look here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog
from ui_imagedialog import Ui_ImageDialog

class ImageDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ImageDialog, self).__init__()

        # Set up the user interface from Designer.
        self.ui = Ui_ImageDialog()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        # Make some local modifications.
        self.ui.colorDepthCombo.addItem("2 colors (1 bit per pixel)")

        # Connect up the buttons.
        self.ui.okButton.clicked.connect(self.accept)
        self.ui.cancelButton.clicked.connect(self.reject)
```

Once you've got your .ui files it is a good practice to use (second link, second example - mentoned above) **pyside6-uic** or **pyuic5** - depending of your needs.

Then you're creating class which role is to setup desired QWidget ui converted python module.

So in QtDesigner you're creating a QWidget:
[screen_qt_designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suDrr.png)

then do all your stuff, that it would like to do - place over QLineEdit, QPushButtons, etc., then save that file in your project's folder. After that all you have to do is use **pyuic** or **pyside6-uic** with proper settings (look at --help to set the output filename).
Then all you have is a .ui file (which is used in case you would like to add some widget, or change the widget all all) and your generated python class that inherits QObject, eg:

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(800, 600)
        self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
        self.label = QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
```

Then create a another Python file, that inherits this generated class, eg.:

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget
from CreateNewDatabase_ui import Ui_Form

class NewDatabaseWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

That's all. You have your prepared QWidget for adding it into a QStackedWidget. I use it in my own program and it fit me very well.

Edit:
I've forgot about **2 important notes**:

1. Never ever edit your file generated by **pyuic** or **pyside6-uic** program. Whenever you wish to change the .ui file, all changes made to autogenerated code will be lost.
2. It's better to keep all signals/slots, logic mechanism in your QMainWindow class. It's better approach in case of code readability.