# PyQt5 splash screen before main window

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to create a splash screen that shows for 5 seconds before showing the main screen. However, I want the splash screen to be the same window as the main window just with a different image in the middle.

I have looked at [How to change UI in same window using PyQt5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842776/how-to-change-ui-in-same-window-using-pyqt5) but it still was not working...

I have also tried using the QSplashScreen class but I could not get it to work properly. If there is any confusion, please feel free to comment and I will clarify.

Here is my code script:

```
# importing libraries 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys   
 
  
class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
  
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setWindowTitle("key") 
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 350, 500) 
        self.UiComponents() 
        self.show() 
  

    def UiComponents(self): 
        lockButton = QPushButton(self) 
        lockButton.setGeometry(60, 200, 100, 70) 
        lockButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius : 10; border : 1px solid white; background-color : #3A3535") 
        lockButton.setIcon(QIcon('lock.png')) 
        size = QSize(40, 40) 
        lockButton.setIconSize(size)
        lockButton.clicked.connect(self.clickme) 
        

    def clickme(self): 
        print("pressed") 
  

App = QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = Window() 
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys   
 
  
class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
  
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setWindowTitle("key") 
#        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 350, 500) 
        self.resize(350, 500) 
        
        self.UiComponents() 
        self.show() 
  

    def UiComponents(self): 
        lockButton = QPushButton(self) 
        lockButton.setGeometry(60, 200, 100, 70) 
        lockButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius : 10; border : 1px solid white; background-color : #3A3535") 
        lockButton.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))              # ! 'lock.png'
        size = QSize(40, 40) 
        lockButton.setIconSize(size)
        lockButton.clicked.connect(self.clickme) 
        

    def clickme(self): 
        print("pressed") 
  

App = QApplication(sys.argv) 

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
import time
splash = QSplashScreen()
splash.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/splash_.jpg').scaled(366, 568))
splash.show()
splash.showMessage('<h1 style="color:white;">Welcome to use this PyQt5-SplashScreen</h1>', 
                   Qt.AlignTop | Qt.AlignHCenter, Qt.white)    
time.sleep(5)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
window = Window()
splash.finish(window)     # +++

sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image]

---

> that just loads the image and then the window. Is it possible to have the image load on the same window (just the plain black screen), and then the main window loads?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui 
from PyQt5.QtCore import * 
import sys   
 
  
class Window(QMainWindow): 
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
  
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: black;")
        self.setWindowTitle("key") 
#        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 350, 500) 
        self.resize(350, 500) 
# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        self.label = QLabel(self)
        self.label.resize(350, 500)
        self.label.setPixmap(QPixmap('images/splash_.jpg').scaled(350, 500))
        QTimer.singleShot(5000, self.UiComponents) 
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        self.show() 

    def UiComponents(self): 
        self.label.hide()                                                      # +++
        
        lockButton = QPushButton(self) 
        lockButton.setGeometry(60, 200, 100, 70) 
        lockButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius : 10; border : 1px solid white; background-color : #3A3535") 
        lockButton.setIcon(QIcon('im.png'))                                    # ! 'lock.png'
        size = QSize(40, 40) 
        lockButton.setIconSize(size)
        lockButton.clicked.connect(self.clickme) 
        lockButton.show()                                                      # +++

    def clickme(self): 
        print("pressed") 
  

App = QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

[image]

Comment: when i run that, i get a message: QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap. Then, nothing shows for 5 seconds and then it shows me my main window @S. Nick

Comment: @Hhggg Change `mages/splash_.jpg` to your image.

Comment: @Hhggg   `splash.setPixmap(QPixmap('lock.png').scaled(366, 568))`

Comment: that just loads the image and then the window. Is it possible to have the image load on the same window (just the plain black screen), and then the main window loads? @S. Nick

Comment: I dont want two different windows to load... I just want this loading window with just a picture to display for 5 seconds before the main window shows @S. Nick

Comment: @Hhggg  I added as you want, please ask questions more clearly.