# Displaying multiple questions one at a time in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to create a GUI that essentially goes through a series of yes/no questions with the user. I want to avoid making it look like a checklist where the user scrolls down to see the next question and so on. So I think it would be more user friendly if I display a single question in the GUI at a time, the user answers, clicks next, and the GUI then shows the next question.

I am familiar with python so I wanted to do this in PyQt5. But many of the tutorials show how to let the user just see a static GUI and nothing similar to what I wanted to implement above. Which examples or class from PyQt5 would be able to do what I want?

Comment: Try QStackedWidget. - Also, duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55842776/how-to-change-ui-in-same-window-using-pyqt5